# How to paste mulple excel range as picture to outlook at the same time

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

please help me fix this. I'm new to this area and I would like to paste multiple set of range from excel and paste it onto an outlook email with modified size. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Here's my current code:

```
Sub EmailSend()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim StrBody As String

    StrBody = "Please see our current Report"

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = Range("C4:D8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = "x"
        .CC = "x"
        .BCC = "x"
        .Subject = "RRF for Vendor Sourcing - " & Cells(3, 2)
        .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to tell us what `RangetoHTML` is.

Comment: It is a UDF made by Ron de Bruin. I'm not sure if there are other codes that I can use that why I'm using "RangetoHTML". Please let me know.

Comment: You need to tell us what RangetoHTML is.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is what defines your range.

```
 Set rng = Range("C4:D8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

You can simply define another range :

```
Dim rng2 As Range     
Set rng2 = Range("J4:N8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

and then make another call to RangetoHTML() using that second range:

```
RangetoHTML(rng2)
```

which will return another string of html which you can then concatenate like this:

```
 .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng2)
```